# VB.NET Custom Listview - How do you get the imagelist?

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have some code im working with to add icons to subitems. It's working great but now I have the need to center the icon in the subitem column. To do this I need to redraw the icon under the DrawSubItem event. How can I tie into the listviews assigned imagelist? (I am using Inherits Windows.Forms.ListView)

Thanks!

```
Private Sub lvResult_DrawSubItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs)
    If e.SubItem.Text = "" Then
        Dim xpos = e.SubItem.Bounds.Location.X + (e.SubItem.Bounds.Width / 2) - 8
        Dim p As New PointF(xpos, e.SubItem.Bounds.Location.Y)
        e.DrawBackground()

          e.Graphics.DrawImage(***NEED IMAGE HERE FROM THE IMAGELIST***, p)
    Else
        e.DrawDefault = True
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: if you subclassed it, you should be using the `OnDrawSubItem` rather than consuming the event.  Then, use the index from `e` to know which image to use from the related imagelist.  Is there text in these subitems, or is it reserved for the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the property for it:

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(Me.SmallImageList.Images("myImage")...
```

Obviously, you should do some error checking to make sure the image exists, etc.

But this illustrates why you are probably going down the wrong path with this since your custom control now needs to know about some images that exist on your form.  Not a good object oriented design.  It doesn't sound like you need a custom control.

Comment: thank you thats what i needed. im not getting to advanced with this thing just using a custom control so i can center the icon and get the double buffering